# Ошибка "Unable to instantiate activity"

Tags: java, android

```
package com.example.myapplication77;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.TextView;




public abstract class Main extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnAttachStateChangeListener{
    private Button btnAdd, btnsub, btndivide, btnmul;
    private TextView tvresult;
    private EditText etfirst, etsecond;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        init();
    }

    public void init() {
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnAdd);
        btndivide = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnDivide);
        btnsub = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnSubtract);
        btnmul = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnMultiply);
        etfirst = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etFirstNumber);
        etsecond = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etSecondNumber);
        tvresult = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvResult);

        btnAdd.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        btnsub.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        btndivide.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);
        btnmul.setOnClickListener((View.OnClickListener) this);

    }

    public void onClick(View v) {
        String num1 = etfirst.getText().toString();
        String num2 = etsecond.getText().toString();
        // по id определеяем кнопку, вызвавшую этот обработчик
        switch (v.getId()) {
            case R.id.btnAdd:
                int addition = Integer.parseInt(num1) + Integer.parseInt(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(addition));
                break;
            case R.id.btnSubtract:
                int subtraction = Integer.parseInt(num1) - Integer.parseInt(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(subtraction));
                break;
            case R.id.btnDivide:
                try {
                    int division = Integer.parseInt(num1) / Integer.parseInt(num2);
                    tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(division));
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    tvresult.setText(String.valueOf("Cannot Divide"));
                    break;
                }
            case R.id.btnMultiply:
                int multiply = Integer.parseInt(num1) * Integer.parseInt(num2);
                tvresult.setText(String.valueOf(multiply));
                break;
        }  } }
```

ошибка

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
                  Process: com.example.myapplication77, PID: 5701
                  java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to instantiate activity ComponentInfo{com.example.myapplication77/com.example.myapplication77.Main}: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.myapplication77.Main> cannot be instantiated
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2567)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477)
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119)
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886)
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
                   Caused by: java.lang.InstantiationException: java.lang.Class<com.example.myapplication77.Main> cannot be instantiated
                      at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Native Method)
                      at android.app.Instrumentation.newActivity(Instrumentation.java:1078)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2557)
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2726) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap12(ActivityThread.java) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1477) 
                      at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102) 
                      at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:154) 
                      at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6119) 
                      at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:886) 
                      at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:776)
```

---

**UPDATE:**

После убирания `abstract` стал выдавать такую ошибку:

> Error:(23, 9) error: Main2 is not abstract and does not override
>   abstract method onViewDetachedFromWindow(View) in
>   OnAttachStateChangeListener Error:Execution failed for task
>   ':app:compileDebugJavaWithJavac'. Compilation failed; see the compiler
>   error output for details.

Answer (score 2):

Уберите модификатор `abstract` из объявления класса активности.

Comment: Если убрат то дает ошибку . что нужно писать вместе abstract

Comment: Ошибку сюда скопируйте.

Comment: Либо уберите и `implements View.OnAttachStateChangeListener`, либо переопределите методы `onViewAttachedToWindow(View v)` и `onViewDetachedFromWindow(View v)`.